# Using Redis with Node.js front end+back end

Tags: database, node.js, web, redis

I'm making a web tool using node js that needs to take in a large amount of data constantly and serves this to a user.  So that each new user does not have instantiate an enormous number of listeners and process all of the data locally, I am making a node.js back-end which takes in all data and pushes processed data to a Redis database.

I then want a separate front-end, where users are fed data from this same Redis db.

I have seen many tutorials explaining how to create a Redis server with Node.js, which is what I need for the back-end, but I need my front-end to connect to an existing Redis db created by my back-end. Is there an easy way to do this?

Also the server this is all running on is already running 2 redis db's.  Is that going to be a problem? I don't see a way to establish a db number on Node.js ass I would when created a Redis db python for example.

Thanks

David

Comment: What do you mean by establish db number on Nodejs ? and I also couldn't understand where does python fit it :(

Answer (score 1):

Having two DBs is not a problem (as long as your server can handle it)

You can also use AngularJS to build your front end or Express Framework to use Redis data for front-end.

What I could understand of your question is:

You can have two nodejs apps, one stores data the other one uses that data to visualise whatever you want to make of it.